# Manipulate a child of a child using d3js

Tags: d3.js

I just want to update background color a particular column using d3.js, id="tr1id" in my case

```
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="tr1id">
                One
            </td>
            <td>
                Two
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This is changing the color of both the tds. Now, I just want to change backgroup of td with id = "trid"

```
  d3.select("tr").selectAll("td").style('background-color','yellow');
  d3.select("tr").selectAll("td").select(".tr1id").style('background-color','blue');
```

I want to use d3.js only to do this. not jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the valid CSS selector for your id is

`#tr1id`

where as the one you have used is for elements with the class tr1id:

`.tr1id`

Secondly, the d3 selections do not allow you to reselect at the same level as the previous selection see:

> the subselection methods, selection.select and selection.selectAll,
>   restrict selection to descendants of the selected elements.

https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selecting-elements

Therefore you must make the selection of the td by ID when you select the td elements like so:

```
d3.select("tr").selectAll("td").style('background-color','yellow');
d3.select("tr").select("td#tr1id").style('background-color','blue');
```

As pointed out in the comments the ID should be unique so this element can be selected by ID alone:

```
d3.select("tr").select("#tr1id").style('background-color','blue');
```

Comment: the id's should be unique so no need to specify that is a `td` tag with that particular `id`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the background-color color of id="tr1id", you can use the CSS selector for ids (prefixed by "#" and not ".", which is for classes). In your case :

```js
d3.select("#tr1id").style('background-color','blue');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="tr1id">
            One
        </td>
        <td>
            Two
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```